# docker up and running on my Mac but "sam local invoke" command results in Error: Running AWS SAM projects locally requires Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-sam-cli

I have Docker up and running on my Mac. But "sam local invoke" command results in  Error: Running AWS SAM projects locally requires Docker. Have you got it installed and running?

Anyone knows what could be the reason?

Comment: `docker` command line is working for you?

Comment: @erik258 ,  yes , I am able to run "docker ps" and "docker run hello-world" commands successfully.

Answer (score 9):

I installed Docker using the GUI with all default presets and I was having the same issue. I fixed this same issue using Docker's dashboard.

Settings -> Advanced -> **Allow the default Docker socket to be used (requires password)**

By enabling it, it *"Creates /var/run/docker.sock which some third-party clients may use to communicate with Docker Desktop"*

Comment: using the docker host variable didn't work for me. I spent hours hunting through the internet and this was what helped. 
Mac pro 16 2019 (intel) Sonoma

Answer (score 8):

There was a change Docker Desktop's default [context settings](https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/).

On Mac, it may default to `desktop-linux` if symlink to `/var/run/docker.sock` was not created. This seems to cause problem with SAM CLI (and probably, a lot of other apps) that expects to communicate with Docker using this socket.

The easiest way to fix this is to set `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable to point to the socket file associated with `desktop-linux`.

Run `export DOCKER_HOST="unix://Users/<username>/.docker/run/docker.sock"`

(add this to your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc` file so that you don't have to define the variable every time you start a shell)

and then try running sam command.

Comment: It works! After running this command and then `sam local invoke`, it began building the image.

Comment: You Sir are a hero. This worked as expected on my macbook.